# Lost reputation with no indication as to why

Tags: support, reputation, specific-user

I appear to have lost 75 reputation with no indication as to why. On meta it shows the 14019 but in the main site it shows 13944. I was wondering what happened (wasn't sure if this is the correct place to ask this but figured I'd try).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Need to prove: $| a + 1/a | \geq 2$ for $a \neq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156621/need-to-prove-a-1-a-geq-2-for-a-neq-0) was deleted by vote, and your answer to that question went with it. You can see this if you check the box that says "show removed posts" which is at the bottom of [your reputation list](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation).

Comment: I looked in my recently deleted posts and I didn't see it. I guess I was looking in the wrong place. Thanks.

Comment: I can see the post in [this list](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/187867), but that list is sorted by date answered, not date deleted (this seems wrong).

Comment: That's why I missed it then. I was looking at the top.

Comment: It is  "recent deleted" not "recently deleted." The deciding factor for inclusion is the age of the post not the time passed since the event of deletion.  This makes the sorting criteria more reasonable too.

Comment: I still would think there would be some indication of why the reputation was lost. I've gotten recent messages saying reputation was lost because a user was deleted, for example.

Comment: @MattSamuel If you check the "show removed posts" box at the bottom of the reputation tab of your profile, such events will be listed in your reputation history.

Comment: @MattSamuel: I believe that that would take an SE wide code change to include "question deleted" events to the reputation lists, similar to the "user removed" events. Depending on how prevalent the deletion of answered questions is on other sites, and on how hard the code change is, the developers might be swayed to add such events.

Comment: @DanielFischer Nice hidden feature, thanks.

Comment: @DanielFischer: That was the checkbox I was trying to suggest. Thanks. I've edited my post to link to that (but my link will only be relevant to Matt).

Comment: Re: but my link will only be relevant to Matt. Wouldn't link like this work for any user who is logged in?  `http://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation` http://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation

Comment: @MattSamuel "Reputation was lost because a user was deleted" is exactly what it says. When a user who has voted on your posts is deleted, their votes and their effect on your rep are also wiped.

Comment: @epimorphic that's not what happened this time though.

Comment: @epimorphic if you read the answer you're commenting on you would see that the cause has been identified.

Comment: @MattSamuel Sorry, misread your second-to-last comment. My initial comment is limited to your earlier comment about the hit from user deletion.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Yes, thanks. I keep forgetting about `users/current`. I will update my post.